# What is type of 123_456_789?

Tags: swift, types

I see in Swift examples values like `123_456_789`, numbers with underscores. What type do these values have by default?

Does it depend on the type of the variable I assign them to? They look quite funny and new to me, so I wonder, how are they treated if they are thrown just like they are, without defining a type?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the documentation
(The Swift Programming Language -> Language Guide -> The Basics
-> [Numeric Literals](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID323)):

> Numeric literals can contain extra formatting to make them easier to
>   read. Both integers and floats can be padded with extra zeros and can
>   contain underscores to help with readability. Neither type of
>   formatting affects the underlying value of the literal:
>
> ```
> let paddedDouble = 000123.456
> let oneMillion = 1_000_000
> let justOverOneMillion = 1_000_000.000_000_1
> ```

So your `123_456_789` is a integer literal, and identical to `123456789`.
You can insert the underscores wherever you want, not only as a
"thousands separator", such as  `1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_9` or `1_23_4567_89`, if you like to write obfuscated code.

Comment: Can I forget about any potential inconsistencies and just treat these as integers without underscores in my operations, using underscores wherever I find it handy?

Comment: @SergeiBasharov: I don't understand your question. 123_456_789 and 123456789 are the same integer. You could even write it as 1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_9 :)

Comment: I mean, if I find it more convenient to use underscores for large numbers, I just can use them and treat values as regular integers in all possible cases?

Comment: @SergeiBasharov: You can insert underscores wherever you want to. It does not change the integer constant. The compiler treats 123456789 and 1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_9 as identical integer literals.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

123_456_789 is an "integer literal" just like 123456789. "integer literal" is a type separate from Int or Int32 or Int8 or whatever. An "integer literal" can be assigned to any integer type (unlike for example an Int value which can only be assigned to an Int).

If you ask "can I treat them as integers", that doesn't make sense. It's a different type. For every type there are rules how it can be used. The rules for Int and "integer literal" are different.